# Evaluating the integral $\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{y}{1+xy}dxdy$

Tags: multiple-integral

Suppose I am evaluating the integral

$$\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{y}{1+xy}dxdy$$

So I consider the following indefinite integral

$$\int\frac{y}{1+xy}dx=y\cdot\frac{1}{y}\int\frac{1}{1+xy}d(1+xy)=\ln|1+xy|$$

But since it may happen that $y=0$, I am wondering if I can do so legally.

Comment: Why did you feel the need to multiply and divide by zero? Considering that $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \log|1+xy| = \frac{y}{1+xy}$, you can go from the fist to the last expression directly.

Comment: @PierreCarre fist $\to$ first

Comment: @PierrreCarre Multiplying and dividing by $y$ are two separate steps. One is to pull to constant $y$ out, the other is to change the $dx$ to $d(xy+1)$.

But I think I get your idea of differentiation. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of the intermediate calculations, the fact that $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\log|1+xy|\right) = \frac{y}{1+xy}$, immediately proves that, in the domain of definition of both expressions ($1+xy \ne 0$), you have $\int \frac{y}{1+xy} dx = \log|1+xy| + C$. So, regarding the base problem, you can write that
$$
\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{y}{1+xy} dx dy = \int_0^1(\log(1+y) - \log 1) dy = [(1+y)\log(1+y)-y]_0^1 = \log 4 -1
$$